# Is a single FET a good way to drive a 100kHz signal through short coax?

Tags: transmission-line, coax

I'm trying to transfer a small (1V)  variable frequency signal over about a metre of coax.  I'm not interested in anything above 100 kHz. One thing to note is that my signal already comes with a +24VDC offset.  So I have this:-

[image: FET driver]

based on this from a proper coax driver datasheet ([Intersil HA-5002](https://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/ha-5/ha-5002.pdf) driver):-

[image: HA-5002 driver]

The HA-5002 is essentially a current amplifier, so I have my FET set up as a voltage follower.  The Spice simulation seems to suggest that it works, with the expected 50% signal reduction at the end of the coax.  The response is -5dBV over the 100kHz bandwidth.  R1 (1.5k) runs a little warm as it's getting towards the top end of its power dissipation, but heat sinking a coax driver doesn't seem unusual.

This circuit seems very simple and the question is, therefore, is it too simple?

PS.  I've looked at many driven coax arrangements here and elsewhere.  The way it's done seems uncertain with 50Ω resistors, here or there. Sometimes there's just one 100Ω resistor at the source.

Comment: Lowercase k for kilo.

Comment: What is the amplitude of the AC signal? Your LTSpice simulation shows 2 V peak-peak...is that correct?

Comment: @ThePhoton 2 Vp-p is correct.

Comment: Watch you don't bust the Vgs abs max during the startup transient.

Comment: You say that you have a AC signal ontop of 24V DC. But C1 in your schematic get's rid of that DC component. Is there any reason why you don't put the FET behind C1?

Answer (score 3):

With 100 kHz at 1 meter, your transmission line length is 1/3000 the vacuum wavelength of the signal. Maybe 1/2000 of the wavelength in the transmission line. Unless you have some really extreme requirements about signal fidelity, you don't even need to worry about transmission line terminations in this system. If you want maximum signal transmission, you can certainly eliminate either the source (R3) or load (R4) termination from this system. Most likely you can elminate both with no ill effects.

Second, your schematic shows the signal source has 2 V peak-peak AC signal on top of the 24 V DC offset.

With this signal, I disagree with the two previous answers. You can arrange this so the FET will remain in saturation (the FET equivalent of "forward active mode" for BJTs) and your driver will have low output impedance throughout the signal's cycle. You won't see any meaningful asymmetry in the output. To do this you have to arrange things so the FET is always sourcing current into the rest of the circuit.

Currently you have maybe 13 mA bias current (conservatively assuming 4 V \$V_{gs}\$ for the 2n7002) through R1, and you're switching 10 mA signal into the transmission line, so your FET will remain saturated throughout the signal cycle.

If you eliminate the source termination (R3) the signal current driven by the FET will increase, and you'll have to decrease the value of R1 to have enough bias current through the FET to keep it saturated.

Comment: No, there's no component > 100 kHz.  Are you suggesting that simple wires are good enough?  It's so difficult to ascertain with any certainty when to use coax.  I know it's for a much longer coax, but https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/113488/56469 is down to 300 **Hz** before going to normal wires.

Comment: @paul, a typical rule is to consider transmission line effects when your line length is more than 1/20 or 1/10 of the signal wavelength.

Answer (score 1):

R1 needs to pull down 1V against a 100 ohm load, or you'll find a very distorted output waveform.

That suggests you need to be able to sink at least 10mA through it. With its current value you'll need to bias the FET so that there's >=15V across R1 - or alternatively, reduce its value.

By the time it can sink 10mA (plus a safety margin, I'd suggest 15-20mA) you'll find the power consumption of this simple buffer is fairly high. If you're OK with that - it's a Class A amplifier - then go for it. If that hurts your battery life ... well, that's why Class B and other more complex topologies were invented.

Comment: Should have said, it's ultimately mains powered.  FET's biased to 24V - it's probably unclear on the schematic.

Comment: Since it's actually 2Vp-p, read 20mA instead of 10mA.

Answer (score -1):

R1 is mismatched to the impedance of what the signal is driving.  The FET may have low output impedance when the input signal is going high, but R1 is the only thing pulling the signal low.  This will cause significant asymmetry in the rising and falling slew rates, which will result in distortion.

A single transistor inherently drives a line assymetrically.  A better answer would be something that has low output impedance compared to the 100 Ω it must drive, and symmetric high/low drive capability.  A opamp in voltage follower configuration seems like a appropriate choice here.

Comment: He has 2 V peak-peak signal around a 24 V offset. He will not be taking the FET out of saturation mode, and the output impedance of the FET will remain relatively constant for both the falling and rising edges of the signal.

Comment: @TheP: That doesn't add up.  No matter what mode the FET is in or what goes on inside this 3-terminal device, it can only source current onto the output.  Lowering the voltage on the output requires sinking current, which only R1 can do.  A better scheme would be to DC couple the FET output by eliminating C1 and R1 altogether, and letting R4 be the pulldown.  Of course worrying about transmission line effects at this frequency and this length is silly in the first place, as you point out in your answer.

Comment: Yes, but with 24 V offset, if R1 is chosen correctly, it will need to continue to source current throughout the signal cycle.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes with the original set up, I get only alight asymmetry  on the sine wave output.  Of course it only 50% due to the R3-R4 voltage divider .